# Different quantity for different size add to cart product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, addtocart, quantity

i've created configurable product which has different sizes and different colors, In my product details page currently there's only one quantity input field and i need to select the size before add to cart. Is there a way i can add multiple quantity input field for each sizes like this :

[image]

Comment: No. For this totally a custom solution needed. Currently you can add only single product to cart at a time. But this seems adding multiple products to cart. Try to check the `wishlist add all products to cart` functionality. You may get some idea from there.

Comment: Maybe you just want a bundled product?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this because you can't add multiple product to cart with different options(size, color etc) in one time.

But you can do this with writing some new functional, as example: create qty inputs for each option and write custom addToCart function with ability to add multiple options product to cart(onto configurable product page).